# Smooth sections of a closed manifold form a complete metric space

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Let $M$ denote a closed, finite-dimensional smooth manifold.

I could not find a single result stating that the set of (smooth) sections of the tangent bundle, i.e. $$\Gamma(TM)=\{s \in C^{\infty}(M,TM) \mid \pi \circ s=id_M\}$$ is a complete metric space (for some metric inducing the strong $C^{\infty}$-topology), so I tried the following:

It is known that the weak and strong topologies on $$X=C^{\infty}(M,TM)$$ agree (because $M$ is compact) and that there exists a metric $d$ on $X$ such that $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space (a standard reference for this is the Differential Topology book by Hirsch).

So if we are able to show that $$\Gamma(TM) \subset X$$ is closed we are done. So let $\left(s_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \Gamma(TM)$ be a convergent sequence of sections with limit $s \in C^{\infty}(M,TM)$. I didn't check it rigorously, but I'm pretty sure that the map $$\Gamma(TM) \to C^{\infty}(M), \; g \mapsto \pi \circ g$$ is continuous with respect to the $C^{\infty}$-topology on both sides. Then $s_n$ converging to $s$ implies that $id_M=\pi \circ s_n$ converges to $\pi \circ s$ and thus $$\pi \circ g= id_M.$$

Is this line of reasoning valid?

Comment: If you know (or assume) that $g\mapsto\pi\circ g$ is continuous, then the space of sections is the inverse image of the singleton $\{id\}$ with respect to a continuous map.

Comment: even easier, thanks! But it seems that there is no way around using the complete metric on the ambient space..

Comment: You don't really need this ambient space. In fact, the space of smooth sections of any smooth fiber bundle over a compact manifold is always a Fréchet space. The way to see this is more or less the same as showing that the space of smooth maps $M\to N$ is a Fréchet space.

Comment: I'm sorry, the space of sections of my previous comment is not a Fréchet space, but a Fréchet *manifold*. Anyway, you may find this awesome paper by Hamilton interesting: https://www.brainmaster.com/software/pubs/math/Hamilton%20Nash%20Moser.pdf

Comment: In particular, the examples at the beginning of section 4.1 should answer all your questions about this matter.

Comment: The reference looks good, thanks alot! Sooner or later I'll need to study Fréchet spaces I guess :D